# Using a single database file in django is feasible?

Tags: python, django

I would like to start a project in django.My doubt is that ,since django is using a single database file. Is that feasible?
Actually planned to create a 'wiki' like application that stores articles in a database.
Using a single database file ??? Will it be?

Comment: You can also use multiple database! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: Or another database provider, like MySQL, that supports different storage schemes.

Answer (score 2):

From the [SQLite3 documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html):

> Generally speaking, any site that gets fewer than 100K hits/day should work fine with SQLite. The 100K hits/day figure is a conservative estimate, not a hard upper bound. SQLite has been demonstrated to work with 10 times that amount of traffic.

So it should be fine to use it in production initially.  If you later have to switch to MySQL or something else that would be considered a "good problem" (ie, you have successfully made a website that gets over 100K hits a day)

Comment: for what it's worth, I have a site on sqlite that gets maybe 1k hits a day, and I get emails from http500 errors almost daily reporting sqlite being locked. Maybe it's caused by something else, not traffic, but never again will I use sqlite in production.

Answer (score 0):

Database file (sqlite3) is meant for development purposes. For any application with reasonable traffic you should choose mysql or postgres

Comment: Using sqlite will cause some problems indeed if there is traffic (multiple users edit the database at the same time) http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5

Comment: I am using mySql...and created a database called 'raas' if i want to use another database named 'xx' how to access it in django??

Comment: Django supports multi-db from version 1.2 onwards. See here for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

Answer (score 0):

try mongo db this is what you are looking for your wiki app

http://blog.montylounge.com/2010/02/11/integrating-mongodb-and-django/

Comment: I am using mySql...and created a database called 'raas' if i want to use another database named 'xx' how to access it in django??